# KnockoutJS: Posting only visible form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have just started using Knockout.js My form has elements which I call questions. I hide/show  them based on user selections. When user hits the submit button I want to post only the visible questions at the time of submit. What I have is this:

```
 // length of Results(questionArray) is 260
            var vmToPost = viewModel;
            delete vmToPost.__ko_mapping__;
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(vmToPost.Results(), function (question) {
                if (!(vmToPost.getQuestion(question.QuestionID()).visible())) {
                    ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem(vmToPost.Results(), question);
                }
            });
```

The util function arrayForEach is behaving strange. It loops through the array very differntly. I had to hit the submit button 7 times to get all the visible elements and come out of the util function. It doesnt throw any error message in the console or the fiddler.
What am I doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html contains a built-in way to skip items from being submitted. It's [the `disabled` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp), which can be controlled using Knockout with the `enable` or `disable` bindings.

```
<div data-bind="visible: visible">
    <label>Name: <input name="name" data-bind="enable: visible"></label>
</div>
```